# Basic topology exercise with $\mathbb{R}^n$ endowed with infinity norm

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

NOTE: This isn't a homework question, nor am I a student at Oxford. I'm just trying to do this for the sake of learning.

I'm trying to solve [exercise 1](http://www0.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/coursematerial/2014/984/99/topexs2-2014.pdf)

My attempt:

a)

$B(\mathbf{x},\epsilon)=((x_1-\epsilon,x_1+\epsilon),...,(x_n-\epsilon,x_n+\epsilon))$.

Choose $\mathbf{y}$ such that each $y_i$, for $i\in \{1,...,n\}$, is in the interval $(x,x_i+\epsilon)$. This is possible, as $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Then, choose $\delta$ to be between $d(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$ and $x_i+\epsilon$, where $i$ is such that $y_i-x_i$ is maximal. Again, this is possible because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

b)

From part a), the given family is evidently a basis for the Euclidean Topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$. But how can I show that it's countable?

Comment: To show countability, each of your sets in part (a) can be described by $n+1$ rational numbers (the $n$ coordinates of the centre of the ball, and the radius). So your family of sets injects into $\mathbb{Q}^{n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks! So is my argument for part (a) correct? (I don't have anyone to check it with)

Comment: I'll take a look a little later for you.

Comment: The idea for part a) is correct, although what you've written is actually wrong.

Firstly, just some notation - we should write:

$$B(x,\epsilon) = (x_1-\epsilon,x_1+\epsilon) \times \cdots \times (x_n - \epsilon, x_n+\epsilon)$$

But secondly, when choosing $\delta$, you should take it to be **less than** both $d(x,y)$ and $x_i + \epsilon - y_i$, not what you wrote.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But if $\delta$ is less than $d(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$, then wouldn't $\mathbf{x}$ be outside of $B(\mathbf{y},\delta)$?

Comment: Oh, yes, of course - I missed that part of the question! In that case, you should also be careful to take $y_i$ between $x_i$ and $x_i + \epsilon/2$, and then take:

$$
d(x,y) < \delta < x_i + \epsilon - y_i
$$

Taking $y_i$ in the restricted range above makes sure that this interval isn't the "wrong way round".